# SQL- Need to write query that will pull all address book entries that have a count > 1. I am stuck

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  
    a.AddressBookID, a.TaxID, a.BusinessName, 
    a.VendorName1, a.VendorName2, a.FirstName, a.LastName, 
    a.Address1, a.Address2, a.City, a.[State], a.ZipCode, 
    a.WorkPhone, a.MobilePhone, a.Active
    (SELECT COUNT(ab.taxid) AS totaltaxid
     FROM addressbook ab (NOLOCK)
     JOIN AddressBook abc ON ab.AddressBookID = abc.AddressBookID
     HAVING COUNT(ab.taxid) > 1) 
FROM 
    AddressBook AS a (NOLOCK)
JOIN  
    Payment AS p (NOLOCK) ON a.AddressBookID = p.EntityID
WHERE    
    a.active = 1
```

Tried to write query that will pull all entries in the address book that have been entered more than once with their detailed information.

```
select 
    ab.AddressBookID, ab.AddressBookTypeName, 
    COUNT(ab.AddressBookTypeName) AS 'Name-Dups', 
    ab.TaxID, COUNT(ab.taxid) AS 'TaxID-Dups',
    --, p.PaymentID
    --, p.EntityID
    ISNULL(COUNT(p.CheckNumber),0) AS 'NumPmtsToEntity'
from 
    AddressBook ab (NOLOCK)
left outer join 
    Payment p (NOLOCK) on ab.AddressBookID = p.EntityID -- left outer join because we want AddressBook dups listed even if there is no pmt to vendor
group by 
    ab.AddressBookID, ab.TaxID, ab.AddressBookTypeName
    --, p.PaymentID--, p.EntityID
having COUNT(ab.taxid) > 1
order by ab.TaxID
```

Comment: What is your real question?  Your title mentions one table but your query has two.  It is unclear what you really want to do.  How, for instance, do you define a duplicate?

Comment: I cant get the query to return results.  I am joining one table with another.  I need to find all instances where the taxid for a company has been entered more than once and we have made payments to them.

Comment: Please show a schema, sample data, expected results and actual results. If you can do this as a SQLFiddle, all the better.

Comment: First off how do you define entered more than once in the address book and where is your self join defining that?

Comment: Entered more than once would mean there are separate address book ids for each entry.  I apologize, I am new to this site and SQL as a whole

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!